# Postion a child element absolute to the page, even when the absolute positioned parent is moved

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-animations

I position a container absolute to the page. In this container there is a span that I need to position absolute to the page as well, because I want to hide it if it overflows the parent container after it's moved.

It should look like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A5Zi2.gif).

I can only hide the span, if it is a child and the parent has its overflow hidden. But then I can't position both absolute.

My current code looks like this:

```css
.container {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  width: 150px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: black;
  animation: move 2s ease-in-out alternate infinite;
}

.container span {
  position: absolute;
  left: 20px;
  top: 20px;
  color: white;
  font-size: 16px;
}

@keyframes move {
  0% {
    top: 0;
  }
  100% {
    top: 200px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <span>Text</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
    .container {
  
        overflow: hidden;

        position: absolute;

        width: 150px;
        height: 50px;

        background-color: black;

        animation: move 2s ease-in-out alternate infinite;
      }

      .container span {

        position: absolute;

        left: 20px;
        top: 20px;

        color: white;
        font-size: 16px;

        animation: move2 2s ease-in-out alternate infinite;
      }

      @keyframes move {

        0% {
          top: 0;
        }

        100% {
          top: 200px;
        }
      }

      @keyframes move2 {

        0% {
          top: 0;
        }

        100% {
          top: -200px;
        }
      }
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <span>Text</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `position:fixed` with the child and consider `clip-path` instead of overflow to hide the overflow:

```css
.container {
  clip-path:polygon(0 0,100% 0,100% 100%,0 100%);
  position: absolute;
  width: 150px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: black;
  animation: move 2s ease-in-out alternate infinite;
}

.container span {
  position: fixed;
  left: 20px;
  top: 20px;
  color: white;
  font-size: 16px;
}

@keyframes move {
  0% {
    top: 0;
  }
  100% {
    top: 200px;
  }
}

body {
  background:blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <span>Text</span>
</div>
```